# Splitting fraction in Fourier domain into two terms, where one is a derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, partial-fractions

I'm reading a solution to a problem that deals with solving a differential equation using the Fourier transform, and I can't follow one of the steps. In the Fourier domain we have:
$$- {4 \over ({4 + \omega^2})^2} = -{1/2 \over 4 + \omega^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial\omega} (-{1/2 \omega \over 4 + \omega^2})$$
I've done partial fractions, but I have never seen something being split up into two terms where one is a derivative. I would like to know which rules were used to establish this identity. It would also be nice to know where I can read more about these rules.

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivative explicitly and checking if the result gives the correct identity?

Comment: Here is the fixed wolfram alpha link showing that the identity [holds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4+%2F+%284%2Bw%5E2%29%5E2+%3D+-1%2F2%2F%284%2Bw%5E2%29+%2B+d%2Fdw%28-1%2F2w+%2F%284+%2B+w%5E2%29%29+). Here is only the [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdw%28-1%2F2w+%2F%284+%2B+w%5E2%29%29+).